# TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected TensorShapeProto got TensorShapeProto. in tf.keras.layers.Embedding

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I'm Trying to do text Classification with `tensorflow.keras.layers.Embedding`
and Glove.
when I run the code:

```
model.add(Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
 100,
 weights=[embedding_matrix],
 input_length=MAX_LENGTH,
 trainable=False))
```

I get the error :

```
TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected TensorShapeProto got TensorShapeProto.
```

My TensorFlow ver: 1.14.0
I'm using Win-64

Comment: Can you try `pip install -U protobuf`?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to reproduce this issue. Thanks to the [@sclarkson answer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/50545) the bug went away when I did the following:

I. Find file `lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py` in my environment directory

II. Reorder the lines from:

```
from tensorflow.python.eager import context
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
```

to

```
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
from tensorflow.python.eager import context
```

I have the following python environment:

1. Macbook Monterey 12.0.1
2. conda 4.10.3
3. python=3.7.9
4. tensorflow=2.6.0
5. keras=2.6.0